# Intellij Subprocess: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to execute `result_b = subprocess.check_output(['swipl'])`
where swipl is the name of a process. I constantly get the 'No such file or directory' error.

However, if I execute that same statement within the python interpreter, it works. What's going on here? Both running in the same directory and both on the same version. I tried all the things that were mentioned in other stack overflow posts, but to no avail. Is this some kind of $PATH problem?

`result_b = subprocess.check_output(['ls'])` does seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that swipl is under /opt/local/bin/ and Intellij was running in a virtual environment. Changing the python interpreter under configurations seemed to solve it.